# Upload file without waiting for it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I'm guessing this is more of a question around async and await, but part of my application I have to take an external link, and basically upload it to my own CDN as the links expire after a set time.

The uploading of files, remote files to be specific is rather slow so I would like to background the task and not have to worry about how long its taken, as long as I have a URL to it.

I created a storage client like:

```
public class SpacesStorageClient : IStorageClient
{
    private readonly AmazonS3Client _s3Client;
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly string _cdnUrl;

    public SpacesStorageClient(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName, string cdnUrl)
    {
        _s3Client = s3Client;
        _bucketName = bucketName;
        _cdnUrl = cdnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadRemoteFileAsync(string url, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = await HttpUtilities.GetStreamFromUrlAsync(url);
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadStreamAsync(Stream stream, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
            
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = _bucketName,
            Key = $"{directory}/{fileName}",
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = publicRead ? S3CannedACL.PublicRead : S3CannedACL.Private
        };
            
        await transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
        return $"{_cdnUrl}/{directory}/{fileName}";
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadByteArrayAsync(byte[] bytes, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }
}
```

But the uploading of files takes far too long, I want to make `UploadRemoteFileAsync` smart and not have to wait, as my application doesn't need the new link straight away.

By understanding how it constructs CDN url's I believe this is possible but I'm stuck when it comes to the await stuff.

Is it as simple as removing await before UploadStreamAsync or inside it?

Comment: "my application doesn't need the new link straight away" - so just don't await the task returned by `UploadStreamAsync`. I wouldn't expect you to need to change that method, but the method that calls it.

Comment: Thanks, I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

First, make the _cdnUrl property publicly accessible:

```
public string CdnUrl => _cdnUrl;
```

Don't await `UploadRemoteFileAsync`, and construct the url without waiting:

```
_storageClient.UploadRemoteFileAsync(sourceUrl, directory, cdnFileName, true);
```

Construct URL from property and other details:

```
var futureUrl = $"{_storageClient.CdnUrl}/{directory}/{cdnFileName}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with usage scenarios and limitations. You probably want to start the upload, not know its completion status, but have the address you generate in the output of the `UploadStreamAsync` method.

In that case, you can remove `await` only for the actual file download method `transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest)` and still return the result with the address from the `UploadStreamAsync` method to leave the address assignment logic inside the class:

```
public class SpacesStorageClient : IStorageClient
{
    private readonly AmazonS3Client _s3Client;
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly string _cdnUrl;

    public SpacesStorageClient(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName, string cdnUrl)
    {
        _s3Client = s3Client;
        _bucketName = bucketName;
        _cdnUrl = cdnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadRemoteFileAsync(string url, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = await HttpUtilities.GetStreamFromUrlAsync(url);
        // we use await here but inside method UploadStreamAsync we do not
        // wait any operation to complete, so there will be no waiting actually
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadStreamAsync(Stream stream, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
            
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = _bucketName,
            Key = $"{directory}/{fileName}",
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = publicRead ? S3CannedACL.PublicRead : S3CannedACL.Private
        };

        // we run Uploading but don't wait the end of operation and go to the next line of code    
        transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
        return $"{_cdnUrl}/{directory}/{fileName}";
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadByteArrayAsync(byte[] bytes, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        // we use await here but inside method UploadStreamAsync we do not
        // wait any operation to complete, so there will be no waiting actually
        return await UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }
}
```

Also you can remove the address return logic and remove the use of `async`/`await` in the code. So you will manipulate the tasks maually. In this case the user will get back the upload task, for which he can wait to finish via `await` if he wants or discard this task if the result is not important.

```
public class SpacesStorageClient : IStorageClient
{
    private readonly AmazonS3Client _s3Client;
    private readonly string _bucketName;
    private readonly string _cdnUrl;

    public SpacesStorageClient(AmazonS3Client s3Client, string bucketName, string cdnUrl)
    {
        _s3Client = s3Client;
        _bucketName = bucketName;
        _cdnUrl = cdnUrl;
    }

    public Task UploadRemoteFileAsync(string url, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = await HttpUtilities.GetStreamFromUrlAsync(url);
        return UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }

    public Task UploadStreamAsync(Stream stream, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(_s3Client);
            
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = _bucketName,
            Key = $"{directory}/{fileName}",
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = publicRead ? S3CannedACL.PublicRead : S3CannedACL.Private
        };
            
        return transferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
    }

    public async Task UploadByteArrayAsync(byte[] bytes, string directory, string fileName, bool publicRead)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        return UploadStreamAsync(stream, directory, fileName, publicRead);
    }
}
```

Remember that in this case you need to change the contract for the interface `IStorageClient` too. And you still have an access to uploading task and can work with it:

```
SpacesStorageClient client = GetSpacesStorageClient();
var uploadingTask = client.UploadRemoteFileAsync(someUrl, someDirectory, someFileName, publicRead);
// wait when uploading is finished
await uploadingTask;
// wait when uploading is finished with blocking
uploadingTask.Wait();

// check if uploading is failed 
if (uploadingTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
{
    // The task completed with an exception
    Exception ex = uploadingTask.Exception;
    // Handle the exception here
}
```

Comment: I like this, it provides more control for later down the line than my answer if I want to pick the task / unit of work back up or wait for it, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @AshSmith you are welcome. I think that it's good for SRP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle to separate uploading logic and path-construction logic but keep control of the uploading. It is not a mandatory rule that all asynchronous calls must be expected immediately, and using `async`/`await` without explicit need will degrade application performance because `.net` builds a state machine in code for each using of async/await.